# TypeScript get first element from union in array with single item

Tags: typescript

How can I get "Message" from `type X = [Message | PartialMessage]` dynamically? I want to conditionally check if I'm dealing with a Message or PartialMessage inside a event listener

```js
interface Message { }
interface PartialMessage { }
interface MessageReaction { }
interface User { }
interface PartialUser { }

interface Events {
    message: [Message | PartialMessage]
    messageReactionAdd: [MessageReaction, User | PartialUser]
}

type EnabledPartials = [Message]

type CurrentEvent = Events["message"]

type FirstFromTuple<T extends any[]> =
  T['length'] extends 0 ? undefined : T[0]

type AnyElementOf<T extends any[]> = T[number];

type ArrayIncludes<T extends any[], U extends any[]> = AnyElementOf<T> extends AnyElementOf<U>
    ? true
    : false

type PartialOrNot = ArrayIncludes<CurrentEvent, EnabledPartials> extends true
    ? CurrentEvent
    : FirstFromTuple<CurrentEvent> // I want the Message part instead
```

Comment: Union types are not positional, there isn't really the concept of first or second

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but out of curiosity, didn't you mean `type X = (Message | PartialMessage)[]`, which is an array of `Message | PartialMessage`, instead of `type X = [Message | PartialMessage]` (an array of a single element)?

Comment: I have added some context to my question @julianobrasil